# Como funciona o getTime

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho 1 script de cookie e ele tem um sistema de time é claro..
gostaria de entender essa contagem:

```
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*2*60*60*1000));
```

Quanto tempo tenho nessa contagem? quanto esse valor daria? *2*60*60*1000
e como posso manipular o valor para 5 minutos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A medida é em milésimos de segundo.

Olhando essa expressão, já se ve que originalmente eram `days * 24` e não `2`.

```
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
             └─────┬──────┘  └┬─┘└┬┘└┬┘└┬┘└─┬─┘
                   │          │   │  │  │   └─ x 1000 transforma segundos em milisegundos
                   │          │   │  │  └───── x 60   transforma minutos em segundos
                   │          │   │  └──────── x 60   transforma horas em minutos
                   │          │   └─────────── x 24   transforma dias em horas
                   │          └─────────────── quantidade especificada em dias
                   └────────────────────────── contados desde a data atual
```

Para 5 minutos, seria isto:

```
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(5*60*1000));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :)